# Title not showing on first loaded image of fancybox gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancyBox version: 2.1.5 with the code below.

The gallery works perfectly and initialises without a problem whichever image I start from.

However no matter which image I start the gallery from, that image (and **only** that image) doesn't show a title. All the other images show their titles correctly but as I go round the images again, the title disappears from whichever image I started from.

Does anyone know how I can get the title to work for the image I start the show from?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui/css/actonians-jqui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css"  type="text/css">
<script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        wrapCSS    : "fancybox-custom",
        closeClick : true,
        closeEffect: "fade",
        openEffect : "fade",

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : "inside"
            },
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    "background" : "rgba(160,160,160,0.65)"
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <p>Click an image below to view full size as a slideshow</p>
    <div class="img_gallery">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="photos/001.jpg" title="Title 1">
                <img src="photos/thumbs/001.jpg" alt="Title 1">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="photos/002.jpg" title="Title 2">
                <img src="photos/thumbs/002.jpg" alt="Title 2">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery1" href="photos/003.jpg" title="Title 3">
                <img src="photos/thumbs/003.jpg" alt="Title 3">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u create a js fiddle

Comment: I would like to think that since you are adding a custom wrapper `fancybox-custom` your titles are not picked up. Try adding the API  option `title: this.title` to force it.

Comment: I haven't customised the "fancybox-custom" css, but it is required (iirc from the documentation) for the "title:inside" option. The titles work on all images other than the first one.

Comment: Apologies for appearing somewhat dim, but could you explain where in the call I should put "title: this.title"? I'm very new to jQuery.

Comment: In the same place along with the other API options like `closeClick : true` etc (see you own code above ;)

Comment: Hi @JFK thank you so much! Adding the `title: this.title` has resolved my problem.  Incidentally I had the same issue with or without the `fancybox-custom` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments as follows:

> Try adding the API option `title: this.title` to force it. – JFK